# How to extend the basis from U to V: Linear Algebra Done right

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $U = \{p ∈ P_4(F) : p(2) = p(5)\}$. Find a basis for $U$. And then extend the basis in part (a) to a basis of $P_4(F)$.

I have found a basis for $U$ using the condition: $\{1, x - \tfrac{3}{609} x^4, x^2 - \tfrac{21}{609}  x^4, x^3 - \tfrac{117}{609} x^4\}$. To extend it to be a basis for $P_4(F)$, is there a systematic way of thinking about the solution?

Comment: What is $F$? Can it be a field with characteristic $3$? Or $7$ or $29$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the standard basis of $P_4(F)$: $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$. If one of these five polynomials doesn't belong to $U$ (and at least one of them has to be outside $U$; otherwise, $U=P_4(F)$), then append it to your basis, and you are done.

In this case, $x$ will do. So, if you append $x$ to your basis, you will get a basis of $P_4(F)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am just wondering if there is a fast way of testing that is not in the U. Like, how do you know x is not in there by looking at my basis? Another question is that, since x is not in U, I would assume I can linearly represent any polynomial in P4(F) using the U's basis. However, I don't think U's basis can represent x^4 by linear combination. Does this mean x^4 is also outside U?

Comment: @BruceZhou If $p(x) = x$ then $p(2) = 2 \ne 5 = p(5)$ so $p \notin U$.

Comment: Yes, $x^4\notin U$, since $2^4\ne5^4$.